# Can I use a java class inside protobuf file?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, micronaut, protobuf-java

I have two java classes, called `MyJavaClass` and `MyAnotherJavaClass`.

MyJavaClass :

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyJavaClass implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    
    private MyAnotherJavaClass myAnotherJavaClass;
}
```

MyAnotherJavaClass:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyAnotherJavaClass implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    private String someField;
    
}
```

Can I have something like this?

```
message MyClassMessage {
   MyJavaClass javaclass = 1;
}
```

Instead of create a message to use protobuf, since I use the same fields.

Comment: I don't think that you can have a class inside the message. You should probably create a corresponding message. Basically a class can have state or not be easily serializable (even if your specific example is), so adding classes to proto is not supported.

Comment: Also, note that protobuf is really geared towards cross-language code generation. If it allowed including arbitrary Java classes as fields, you wouldn't be able to use that message definition from another language.